# matlab radial k-space dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions, polar-coordinates

I have acquired 10 frames of radial k-space data, with 12 spokes each frame. I also have an array of angles for each spoke. The size of kx will be 120. I want to 1)plot the spokes and 2)assign the spokes back into its corresponding frame. How should I arrange the matrix please? My MATLAB code is

```
for s=1:(12*10) %total number of spokes
    ky = tan(deg2rad(angles[i,1]))*kx; %generate the spokes with corresponding angles
    k_space(kx,ky,frame) = raw_data(kx,s); %assign the data to the spoke
    if (i/12)==fix(i/12) %change to the next frame when 12 spokes arrive one frame
       frame=frame+1;
    end 
end
```

The error message was

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

I understand the error appears because the ky has to be integer as a dimension of the 3D matrix `k_space(kx,ky,frame)`. How should I correct this matrix dimension please?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try rounding the coordinates?

Comment: you mean I should round ky? @CrisLuengo

Comment: I think you should try that. It’ll prevent the error for sure. I don’t know if it is the best approach to solve the larger problem, maybe you need to divide the power among neighboring bins? I’m not familiar enough with this to know for sure.